How to prevent users from accessing source code in PyInstaller's onedir output?
I have a PyQt application, and I use PyInstaller to generate the executable. When I use the onedir option, all my source code and files (like Python files, .ui files, images, etc.) are located alongside the .exe file in the dist folder, which makes them accessible to users.
Here is my current .spec file:
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[
        ('views/*', 'views/'), ('components/*', 'components/'), ('lib/*', 'lib/'),
        ('static/image/*', 'static/image/'), ('static/font/*', 'static/font/'),
        ('version', './'), ('en.qm', './'),
        ('fa.qm', './'), ('en.ts', './'), ('fa.ts', './'), ('messages_translation.json', './')
    ],
    hiddenimports=['entities.hospitals', 'lib', 'lib.file_utils', 'src.lib', 'src.lib.tools', 'PyQt5.QtNetwork',],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
a.datas = [data for data in a.datas if not data[0].startswith('pytz')]
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='main',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
    icon='static/image/icon.ico',
)

coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='main',
)


I previously tested the onefile option, but the resulting .exe file was too large, and the application took too long to open.
Is there any way to secure the source code or prevent users from accessing these files in the onedir output? Any help would be greatly appreciated

It depends on how much you're worried about user accessing those files. At some level, they will always be potentially accessible in some way, and the higher level of obfuscation you need, the lower performance you'll get, with the "bonus" of increased complexity, possibly loss of performance and, obviously, higher possibility of bugs and difficulty in maintenance. Simply put, if the program can access those files, the user also can.

I simply want the files, or at least the Python files, to not be easily visible. I'm not really aiming to make them completely undiscoverable.

"Undiscoverable" and "invisible" are not the same, and they are not the same as readable. What does actually affect the size of the package? If it's the resources (images, etc.), then you could consider a middle way: build the package with the "onefile" mode by including only the python code, and distribute the directory with the resulting executable and the "unpackaged" resources.
